# Two recent suggested edits were not attributed to me in my reputation history

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, suggested-edits, serial-voting

I recently suggested two edits to the tag wiki for the [list](/questions/tagged/list) tag (the [body](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/209748) and [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/209749)), but found that they were not attributed to me in my reputation history.

The same day, before suggesting the edits, I had noticed that I had been serial upvoted on 16 of my questions, giving me 80 reputation which (after a quick confirmation in the chat room), I knew *would* be removed whenever the automatic script ran.

Both of my edits were approved the same day (using SO time). I was away so I don't know the sequence of events that led to the reputation mishap, but when I returned, the 80 reputation I had expected to lose was gone, and there was no trace of these two edits in my reputation history. I was not awarded the +2 reputation for either of them, and they don't even show in my history whatsoever.

When visiting my reputation audit, the page states that I've **earned 40 reputation from suggested edits**. Yet, my profile lists that I've had **22** suggested edits approved. These two edits appear in my profile under my activity for suggestions, and both of those pages say "Approved", yet there is no trace of either of them in my reputation history or audit page.

Also, triggering a reputation recalculation did nothing.

Comment: The only thing that come to mind is that those suggestions were approved by the same person who serially upvoted you - maybe reputation from approved edits is removed along with the reputation from upvotes in such cases?

Comment: I know this is quite old, but I am looking through the voting history for Feb 26th, I can see the reputation for the tag wiki edits and things seem to tally up for me. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Oded Yes, seems to have gotten fixed somewhere along the way. No idea when, doubt I would have noticed a random +4 in my reputation.