# Combine serial upvote/downvote reversals into a single event in reputation history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, reputation-history

This has happened to me twice recently. One was serial downvoting here on MSO by a... certain user *glares*... and the other was serial upvoting on SO. When they get reversed, it lists out a ton of "undownvote" or "unupvote" events in my history, like I don't already have enough entries from all the "downvote" or "upvote" events. When the serial vote checker runs, could it not group all of these events into a single, expandable event?

Let's replace this ugly screen:

[image: Before]

With this somewhat nicer looking screen:

[image: After]

It will also give users a somewhat better idea of *why* all these upvotes/downvotes were reversed.

Comment: We're looking at this and should have an answer tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they're not going to answer, here's what the new way looks like:

[image: Voting fraud reversed]

Nice and simple text history item. :) Thanks guys!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot to put an answer here...got distracted.  Indeed we took your suggestion and now roll these up :)

Comment: @Nick: Have you looked at my [other problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123607/141525) which may be connected to the voting fraud system?

Comment: It's on my list...quite a few rep things still on the table and questions that need followup, you can see me littering the active tab with this now.  It'll take a few days to get everything addressed.